# How can I extract a concrete subsample of a dataframe and save in another dataframe in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, subsampling

I have a dataframe called 'df1' which has X rows, suppose 1000. What I want to do is to get a concrete subsample of that dataframe and save as another. For example, I want to extract the rows 400 to 700 from 'df1' and save it as 'df2'.

I know that one possible way is getting the content of 'df1' as a vector with:

```
list = df1.collect()
subsample = list[400:700]
df2 = sc.createDataFrame(subsample, attributes)
```

But my question is: is there any other way of getting the same result not loading the data in a list? I ask this because when you have a huge dataset maybe it will not be efficient loading data with collect and generating another dataframe.

Thanks.

Comment: there is no row numbers in Spark.

Comment: No, but if you have an attribute 'IDENT' which is incremental, equivalent to a representation of a row number?

Comment: then you can just use `filter()`

Answer (score 0):

Pyspark dataframes don't have indexes. You can create one, but note that any shuffle operation (`group`, `join`...) that took place before the creation of the index might have changed the order of your rows.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
start = 400
end = 700
df2 = df1.rdd.zipWithIndex()\
    .map(lambda l: [l[1]] + list(l[0]))\
    .toDF(["index"] + df1.columns)\
    .filter(psf.col("index").between(start, end))
```

Another way is to collect only the first rows of your dataframe into a list:

```py
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(df1.head(end)[start:], df1.columns)
```

or using `Pandas`:

```py
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(df1.limit(end).toPandas().iloc[start:, :])
```